# Use your flags!

Tags: discussion, flags

We moderators can't be everywhere, we can't look at everything that is posted on this site. We need **your** help to moderate it.

You can flag any post or comment for moderator attention. If you see anything where a moderator should be involved, just flag it and shortly explain your reason.

I'd like to direct your attention specifically on comments insulting other users. We have removed quite a few of them now, but they are hardly flagged. We only discover those by accident, **please flag any insults you see**.

If you're unsure, just flag it, we don't get many flags and we'd rather have see some borderline cases than to miss harmful events.

Comment: +10000000000000000000

Comment: Don't forget to mention that the flag can be used for positive mod attention, such as merging answers, promoting comments to answers, activating community wiki, etc.

Comment: K, flagging Borror0 for his "me too" in these comments. :)

Answer (score 1):

Please note that per

https://skeptics.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation

flagging does require a minimum of 15 reputation. Shouldn't be an issue for most, but I did want to mention it.